# What does Dagger do instead of reflection

Tags: android, dagger-2

**[From the docs: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html#DependencyInjection](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html#DependencyInjection)**

[image]

---

It says, it does not use annotations. But I have used annotations like `@Inject`, `@Component`, `@module` ..... How the statement is valid

---

Comment: Dagger uses annotations to create generated code instead of reflection.

Comment: Dagger is a compile-time framework for dependency injection. It uses no reflection or runtime bytecode generation, does all its analysis at compile-time, and generates plain Java source code.

Comment: Annotation processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dagger2 generates a lot of boilerplate and injection code for you, typically these generated objects are prefixed with the word `Dagger` when you try to interact with them. I don't know if this will answer your question or not, but when using Dagger you need to typically first do a build of your application for these classes to be generated before you can actually start using them, and performing a clean and build will regenerate these files for you again (clean deletes, build creates).

as an example:

```
    DaggerAppComponent.builder()
        .application(this)
        .build()
        .inject(this)
```

this `DaggerAppComponent` will only be accessible after doing a build, as it is generated through the dagger framework

The annotations provided by dagger, such as `@Inject` simply tells dagger HOW to generate certain files or where to (for this instance) inject values, these annotations are used to tell dagger how to do stuff instead of being reflection